# Get the composite data from 2 independent mysql table

Tags: mysql

I want fetch the composite data from the two different or independent table.
Here is my structure of tables.

table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE `keywords` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `keyword` (`keyword`)
)
```

in this table data is like:

```
+----+---------+
| id | keyword |
+----+---------+
|  2 | apple   |
|  1 | Banana  |
|  8 | ginger  |
|  6 | grapes  |
|  7 | guava   |
| 10 | milk    |
|  3 | onion   |
|  4 | potato  |
|  9 | tea     |
|  5 | tomato  |
+----+---------+
```

table 2;

```
CREATE TABLE `Rfps` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

in this table data is like:

```
+----+----------------------------------+
| id | subject                          |
+----+----------------------------------+
|  1 | I would like to have some banana |
|  2 | I need some tea                  |
|  3 | I like grapes                    |
|  4 | yes. Beer, Banana, Onion         |
|  5 | capsicum                         |
+----+----------------------------------+
```

My Moto is to fetch the id of subjects in table 2 those have the keywords of table1.

I created one query like:

```
select * from Rfps where CONCAT(subject) REGEXP (select GROUP_CONCAT(keyword SEPARATOR '|') as keyword from keywords);
```

This is giving the result as:

```
+----+----------------------------------+
| id | subject                          |
+----+----------------------------------+
|  1 | I would like to have some banana |
|  2 | I need some tea                  |
|  3 | I like grapes                    |
|  4 | yes. Beer, Banana, Onion         |
|  5 | capsicum                         |
+----+----------------------------------+
```

But not getting the id of keywords, or keyword.

But if i fetch like:

```
select Rfps.id,Rfps.subject,keywords.id,keywords.keyword from Rfps,keywords where CONCAT(subject) REGEXP (select GROUP_CONCAT(keyword SEPARATOR '|') as keyword from keywords);
```

this is giving the data as:

```
+----+----------------------------------+----+---------+
| id | subject                          | id | keyword |
+----+----------------------------------+----+---------+
|  1 | I would like to have some banana |  2 | apple   |
|  2 | I need some tea                  |  2 | apple   |
|  3 | I like grapes                    |  2 | apple   |
|  4 | yes. Beer, Banana, Onion         |  2 | apple   |
|  1 | I would like to have some banana |  1 | Banana  |
|  2 | I need some tea                  |  1 | Banana  |
|  3 | I like grapes                    |  1 | Banana  |
|  4 | yes. Beer, Banana, Onion         |  1 | Banana  |
|  1 | I would like to have some banana |  8 | ginger  |
|  2 | I need some tea                  |  8 | ginger  |
|  3 | I like grapes                    |  8 | ginger  |
|  4 | yes. Beer, Banana, Onion         |  8 | ginger  |
|  1 | I would like to have some banana |  6 | grapes  |
|  2 | I need some tea                  |  6 | grapes  |
|  3 | I like grapes                    |  6 | grapes  |
|  4 | yes. Beer, Banana, Onion         |  6 | grapes  |
|  1 | I would like to have some banana |  7 | guava   |
|  2 | I need some tea                  |  7 | guava   |
|  3 | I like grapes                    |  7 | guava   |
|  4 | yes. Beer, Banana, Onion         |  7 | guava   |
|  1 | I would like to have some banana | 10 | milk    |
|  2 | I need some tea                  | 10 | milk    |
|  3 | I like grapes                    | 10 | milk    |
|  4 | yes. Beer, Banana, Onion         | 10 | milk    |
|  1 | I would like to have some banana |  3 | onion   |
|  2 | I need some tea                  |  3 | onion   |
|  3 | I like grapes                    |  3 | onion   |
|  4 | yes. Beer, Banana, Onion         |  3 | onion   |
|  1 | I would like to have some banana |  4 | potato  |
|  2 | I need some tea                  |  4 | potato  |
|  3 | I like grapes                    |  4 | potato  |
|  4 | yes. Beer, Banana, Onion         |  4 | potato  |
|  1 | I would like to have some banana |  9 | tea     |
|  2 | I need some tea                  |  9 | tea     |
|  3 | I like grapes                    |  9 | tea     |
|  4 | yes. Beer, Banana, Onion         |  9 | tea     |
|  1 | I would like to have some banana |  5 | tomato  |
|  2 | I need some tea                  |  5 | tomato  |
|  3 | I like grapes                    |  5 | tomato  |
|  4 | yes. Beer, Banana, Onion         |  5 | tomato  |
+----+----------------------------------+----+---------+
```

Repetitive rows.

Comment: @Ashraful, thanks for the edit dude!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONCAT()` is putting strings together. Having it only on one column is useless and prevents the potential use of an index.
Regexp is also overkill. Use `LIKE` instead.

This query is giving the correct result:

```
select
*
from
keywords k 
join Rfps r on r.subject like concat('%', k.keyword, '%');
```